# How do I update data from Observable without having to re-subscribe/add disposable where I can delay the rendering of layout.xml until data is loaded?

Tags: android, rx-java, observable, rx-java2

**My ViewModel is returning nullfields for current User how to fix**?

Say I had the following Disposable. `getUserProfile` calls a Retrofit 2 API that returns `Observable<Response<GetUserProfileResponseBody>` when the Activity is started in `onStart`. Is this a one-time call to the Retrofit 2 API? Say the user profile has a bunch of posts and user details which is retrievable in the `Response<GetUserProfileResponseBody>`. I want the user profile to automatically update when stuff changes or gets added, and if it doesn't, I would just swipe down and call `onRefresh`. For example, say in `onStart` I call the following code:

```
public void load(String userId) {
GetUserProfileRequest request = new GetUserProfileRequest(userId);
    Disposable disposable = mViewModel
            .getUserProfile(request)
            .subscribe((Response<GetUserProfileResponseBody> response) -> {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    mViewModel.setCurrentUser(response.body().getCurrentUser());
                }
            }, (Throwable ex) -> {
            });
    mCompositeDisposable.addDisposable(disposable);
}
```

and then I go ahead and edit my profile (in the same activity so `mCompositeDisposable.clear()` is not called). Afterwards, I expect the changes to reflect immediately in the user profile. Do I have to call `load(userId`) one more time, which in turns adds another disposable to composite disposable, or will `Observable` automatically detect the changes from the Retrofit 2 API to update the UI? I want the `Observable` that I'm subscribing to to get updated so I don't have to resubscribe.

Similarly, everytime I swipe refresh, I don't want to call all of `load` which add another disposable either, I just want the thing I'm subscribing to to call the Retrofit 2 API again so I can have updated data in the SAME disposable.

**Update**

In `subscribe` I'm setting current user in viewmodel. At the same time, in a Fragment of this activity, I am accessing the viewmodel field in the layout.xml, but that field is null, because `mViewModel.setCurrentUser` has not yet been called when the layout.xml is rendered.

```
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.skoolar.viewmodels.GetUserProfileViewModel" />

                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_user_avatar"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

How do I delay the rendering of the layout.xml until `mViewModel.currentUser` is rednerred?

Comment: For the first part of the question use interval. The interval() operator will emit an item at a given time interval. http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/interval.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use background polling to automatically refresh the user posts on the profile every X seconds. Lets say you have a `postService` to retrieve user wall feed.

```
Observable.interval(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.io())
      .map(tick -> postService.getRecentPost())
      .subscribe(posts -> {
        // the subscriber is called with List<Message> every time
        // the remote service is polled
        for (Post post : posts) {
          log.info(post.toString())
        }
      })
```